# phabricator how to generate diff url from feed.http-hooks

Tags: phabricator

Phabricator version d2cff6a2cf01396f6337edfadd1f7df7cce1277d (Nov 17 2017)

I want to get url of Differential, like

```
http://myphabricator/D4
```

from requests of feed.http-hooks.

But feed.http-hooks does not send Differential number like D4, send storyID and somethings instead.

How should I create Differential Url from Information of feed.http-hooks?
I did below.

client

```
$ arc diff
(create comment to D4)
```

feed.http-hooks.sent

```
***headers***
Host:localhost:8085
Content-Length:441
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

*** bodys ***
b'storyID=94&storyType=PhabricatorApplicationTransactionFeedStory&storyData%5BobjectPHID%5D=PHID-DREV-ms2ge2gojlaqaqt54szv&storyData%5BtransactionPHIDs%5D%5BPHID-XACT-DREV-vng3mngfk7i44er%5D=PHID-XACT-DREV-vng3mngfk7i44er&storyData%5BtransactionPHIDs%5D%5BPHID-XACT-DREV-2jn767qfhgbr2uh%5D=PHID-XACT-DREV-2jn767qfhgbr2uh&storyAuthorPHID=PHID-USER-jm5w6p3zrpns57e35f5d&storyText=my.name+updated+the+diff+for+D14%3A+test.&epoch=1519094890'

*** params ***
storyText:my.name updated the diff for D14: test.
storyData[transactionPHIDs][PHID-XACT-DREV-vng3mngfk7i44er]:PHID-XACT-DREV-vng3mngfk7i44er
storyData[transactionPHIDs][PHID-XACT-DREV-2jn767qfhgbr2uh]:PHID-XACT-DREV-2jn767qfhgbr2uh
storyAuthorPHID:PHID-USER-jm5w6p3zrpns57e35f5d
storyID:94
storyType:PhabricatorApplicationTransactionFeedStory
storyData[objectPHID]:PHID-DREV-ms2ge2gojlaqaqt54szv
epoch:1519094890
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse out the objectPHID (in this case PHID-DREV-ms2ge2gojlaqaqt54szv), and use a phid.query Conduit call to find the object it refers to:

```
echo '{
  "phids": [
    "PHID-DREV-ms2ge2gojlaqaqt54szv"
  ]
}' | arc call-conduit --conduit-uri http://localhost:8085/ --conduit-token $SECRET phid.query
```

or alternatively using curl instead of arc call-conduit:

```
curl http://localhost:8085/api/phid.query \
-d api.token=$SECRET \
-d phids[0]=PHID-DREV-ms2ge2gojlaqaqt54szv
```